# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'add_comment_to_post'

Tags: python, django

I completed all the steps from the following website: 
https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/homework_create_more_models/

everything seems correct, and for some reason the server cannot be run on cmd.

Below is the error displayed:

```
32\Scripts\mysite\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'add_comment_to_post'
```

Editing urls.py, views.py, forms.py was done several times, and also comment model was added to the database with: "python manage.py makemigrations blog", and "python manage.py migrate blog"

```
urls.py:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),


views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_draft_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_draft_list.html', {'posts':posts})

@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('post_list')

def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)



forms.py:

from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text',)


models.py:


from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the URL patterns in the wrong urls.py; you've put them in mysite/urls.py, the instructions say to use blog/urls.py.